# start at a given offset with KakfaIO

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

I'm using `KafkaIO.read()` and I'd like to start consuming from a specific offset.

At some point there used to be a `KafkaIO.read().withStartFromCheckpointMark()` method to do that.

I see from the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html) that there is a way via:

> KafkaCheckpointMark provided by runner;

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support, but there are couple of options:

- `withStartReadTime()` might be better suited.
- You can create a `group.id` and commit offsets in that group. When you set `group.id` in KafkaConsumer config, KafkaIO defaults to resuming from offsets committed for the group. You can also chose to enable `auto.commit` in KafkaConsumer. See 'Advanced Kafka Configuration' in JavaDoc.