# How Apache Beam starts to consume kafka messages from a specified offset and customizes the storage offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, apache-beam

When I used to consume kafka messages in Spark, I was able to specify consumption from an offset using the following code:

[image: code here]

How do I achieve the same functionality with Apache beam now?

Comment: And how to customize storage offset in Apache Beam?

Comment: AFAIK, Beam just relies on standard Kafka consumer group mechanics. Offsets would only be stored in Kafka

Comment: This answers part of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725043/start-at-a-given-offset-with-kakfaio